# internet explorer non-deterministic layout

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, media-queries

Another internet explorer non-deterministic bug. Bug only occurs in internet explorer (chrome, firefox, safari all work fine).

To produce (see screenshots here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi920.jpg):

1. If I go to https://shick.me/test with a window wider than 600px, the chat messages stick to the left though they should be centered (like in any of the other browsers)
2. If I make the window narrower than 600px, the layout is correct
3. non-deterministic: if I now make the window wider again, the layout is correct!

What workaround is needed, or is anything wrong with CSS/HTML?

Hint: it might be related to the trick with

```
margin-right: 3000px;
padding-right: -3000px;
```

Does that help?

When I work on the page with the developer console (F12 in ie), I see that almost any manipulation fixes the layout instantly. This for instance, redraws the page and fixes it:

```
document.body.style.display = 'none';
document.body.style.display = 'block';
```

However, when I put this into javascript (in onload/domcontentloaded etc.), it does not work - the break happens after the js is executed. When I wrap a `setTimeout` around it, it works - but is a really ugly hack I'd say.

Comment: Now is this a bug with that browser software or with your style rules? What _is_ your claim?

Comment: Since all other browsers work, and ie works after a specific path, I'd definitely claim this to be an ie bug -unless you tell me otherwise.

Comment: Then why the final question "What is wrong with the CSS/HTML?"? The answer to that obviously should be "Nothing" then...

Comment: thanks @arkascha I corrected it ;-)

Comment: @arkascha I don't know how much you know about browser technology. Many browsers have some built-in tolerance. hence a browser displaying a layout "correctly" doesn't necessarily mean the CSS/HTML is "correct". Therefore, it might well be that my code is incorrect and only ie is right.

Answer (score 0):

After some discussions in real life (as opposed to stackoverflow), we ended up viewing the negative-margin "trick" as the culprit that wreaks havoc in ie.

So I chose a different layout and it works fine now.